# Sending ethernet packet to a device with a specific mac address

Tags: iptables, routing

Is it possible to send a ethernet packet targeting a PC with a specific MAC Address?

I am in the following situation, I have at the beginning two devices in the same subnet connected via a switch. `Dev1 - 192.168.0.1` and `Dev2 - 192.168.0.100`. `Dev2` sends data constantly to `192.168.0.1` which is `Dev1` in this case.

Now if someone else joins the network with the same IP as `Dev1`, let's say `Dev3 - 192.168.0.1`, the data sent by `Dev2` could be received by `Dev1` OR by `Dev3`.

Is there a way to ensure that the data is only sent to `Dev1`? Is it possible to add a route somehow in the switch?

Answer (score 1):

You mixed two distinct problems:

1. ARP protocol details.

Your systems know remote MAC address of target system with known IP address by using Address Resolution Protocol. It is really the broadcasted packet in the network: "Hey, who is 192.168.5.34, tell me your MAC address!", and that system replies: "I'm 192.168.5.34, my MAC address is XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX". Then all systems who seen this reply record in their dynamic ARP table that 192.168.5.34 is ..., and for some time they will not query, but send packets for that IP to that MAC address. After some time the record in the table expires, and resolution process repeats. Usually this is 300 seconds.

Of course, if rogue system replies faster than the genuine system, you might have a trouble. This is called ARP spoofing.

You can put static entries into ARP (MAC to IP) table of each computer. If there is static entry for some IP address, its entry never expires, that system will never send ARP resolution request for that IP, and always will use MAC address from static entry. In Linux, it is done like this:

```
ip neighbour add 192.168.5.34 lladdr XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX dev eth1
```

or, if there is already a dynamic entry, replace "add" with "change". You can see the table (all static and dynamic entries and the expiration status) with "ip neigh show".

To persist this during reboot, use a /etc/ethers file, i.e. put MAC addresses of important systems into that file to prevent spoofing.

Also, some switches can implement additional security. I have a D-Link DGS-1210-52 at hand, it has such feature, it is called "Security -> ARP Spoofing Prevention", where you add "static arp" entries on a switch level. This particular switch can store 64 of such entries. In addition, it can bind each entry to some switch port(s). I didn't tried this.

2. Switch work internals

MAC address isn't a thing that is bound to a network card forever. It is just the default setting, which anybody can change. For example, in Linux I can run "ip link set dev eth1 address YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY" and this will change MAC address of the network card (until reboot). I can, therefore, set up MAC address to that of the system whose packets I want to hijack and then the switch again enters into play.

A switch maintains a table which MAC address it sees on which port. This is called MAC address learning. What if same MAC appears on another port? It will think that I just reconnected system to another port and update the table. Entries in that table also expire after some time, but that's not relevant to this question.

Some switches will alert you if some MAC jumps from one port to another and back, some not. DGS-1210-52, for example, will not.

But, you can add static entries into this forwarding table, so the port where MAC in question should be will not be determined by the learning, but you configure it into switch.

There also some other security-related features. Some switches can auto-bind the first few MAC addresses they see on the port, and will shutdown port is there are more. I.e. you don't configure MAC into switch, it will be autoconfigured on first system connection, then to connect another computer to same port you will need to reset port security on the switch. (I used this with Cisco SF300 switches.) And so on.

So, read your switch manual.